# The view 'Route' was not found, but it actually exist in nopcommerce 4.5.2

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, view, controller, nopcommerce

Appears:
**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view '/OGS/Route.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched: /OGS/Route.cshtml**

Although the file is present on the first path:
**Nop.Web => Areas => Admin => Views => OGS => Route.cshtml**

Here is the controller code,

```
public class OGSRoute : BaseAdminController
{
  public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
  {
    return View("/OGS/Route.cshtml");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this viewName: Areas/Admin/Views/OGS/Route.cshtml

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View("Areas/Admin/Views/OGS/Route.cshtml");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change like below

```
  public partial class OGSRouteController : BaseAdminController
    {
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View("Areas/Admin/Views/OGS/Route.cshtml");
        }
    }
```